# How to implement angular js website with question mark in url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, url, url-encoding

I am new to angularJs.
    I have a issue when I am working on an app with angularjs and ruby on rails at the backend.
Whenever i have a '?' in the url it gets converted into %3f in the url and hence giving a wrong output.

The question I have is that can i somehow bypass the question mark in the url so that I can get the proper Url.

For eg:-

The following url `$location.path("www.test.com/program/who-is-this?")` gets converted into below url

```
"www.test.com/program/who-is-this%3f"
```

I want a question mark instead of %3f in the url.
I have gone through some of the questions on the forum but it is not helping me much.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

$locations's path method only operates with angular's part of url (the one, that usually after '#' symbol). You may want to use [$location.url](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#methods_url) method to be able to replace part, that contains '?' symbol.

Comment: I tried $location.url("www.test.com/program/who-is-this?").It removed Question mark from url..Actually I want to display the question mark in the url.

Comment: @PeeVee I suppose, modifying url in this way (adding '?' symbol) will lead to page reload. That's why AngularJs (Single Page Application framework) may not provide such API.

Comment: @andrey-shustariov..Is there any other way you can suggest by which we can implement the above.